# url rewriting for jhipster

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, jhipster

I have a question and I don't know if it's possible.
I'm trying to remove the '#' in my jhipster website urls AND I saw that's difficult to do in my code.

exemple:
http://www.exemple.com/#/test -> http://www.exemple.com/test

So, is it possible to do that with an other way ? Like .htaccess or something else ?

I just want to precise, I'm working with an old version of jhipster and it's an angularJS application.

I'm generating the .war and i'm deploying it on a dedicated server with apache2 and my application is using the port 8000 so I made conf for virtual hosts. Maybe I can add something here ?.

Comment: Please clarify your question, do you want to do this without having to change your app? If you are OK with modifying your app, have you tried the tip documented on jhipster site? https://jhipster.github.io/tips/010_tip_configuring_html_5_mode.html

Comment: Exactly, i don't know how to clarify... my question is in the tittle. Can i do URL rewriting ?

Comment: Not clear enough to get help. Why don't you want to apply the tip, it's easy for angular 1? Whch technology: reverse proxy, nginx, apache? Please edit your question rather than adding comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that in AngularJs -

Basically you need # for non-html browsers or else without that they will make a http call.(So it is used for old browsers).
You can tell angular to use HTML5 mode-

In route config add html5Mode(true); at the end.
 eg-

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl:'/views/home.html'
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
});
```

In Html head tag add base tag -

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">    
<base href="/">
</head>
```

Comment: This is the angularjs way! I want to know if i can rewritte